# NetBeans 8.2 - next tab / previous tab shortcuts not working

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

When I upgraded to NetBeans 8.2 on two separate Windows 7 computers I've lost possibility to use `Ctrl + PageUp` and `Ctrl + PageDown`, which switch tabs.

I had to reassign the shortcuts to other, far worse combinations. It's just these shortcuts don't work any longer in NB 8.2, however they're listed in the settings page.

*Note:* the same shortcut works in Notepad++, so it's not some OS issue.

Any ideas on that one? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

i ran into the same issue using netbeans 8.2 on ubuntu 16.04

for me, the problem was the Nimbus look-and-feel. running with "--laf Metal" or omitting the laf entirely fixed the problem for me. i'm not able to test on win7, but it's worth experimenting with the laf value

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=268968

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Ubuntu as a Parallels VM on Mac, this worked for me:

- Go to your VM's "Configure..." menu
- Select "Mouse & Keyboard"
- Click "Open shortcuts preferences..." button
- Select "Application shortcuts"
- **Uncheck** "Show Previous Tab" and "Show Next Tab" (yes, it's counterintuitive)
- Make sure you have your keyboard shortcuts set in Netbeans for Ctrl+Tab & Ctrl+Shft+Tab